# Facing problem while connecting OpenViBE Acquisition Server with Python

Tags: eeg, experimental-neuroscience

I am trying to connect OpenViBE Acquisition Server with Python (without using OpenViBE Driver). I read the OpenViBE documentation (http://openvibe.inria.fr/how-to-use-labstreaminglayer-in-openvibe/) under the heading 'Acquisition Server -> LSL' and I followed the same steps.

While there is no problem in connecting Acquisition Server and LSL, when I press 'Play' it shows this error ->

```
[ERROR] Could not find EEG stream: could not instantiate device for serial: EE225-020034-000289
[ERROR] Starting failed !
```

[image]

I am using OpenViBE Acquisition Server v3.5.0(32-bit) and ANT-Neuro eego-mylab Amplifier.

I am working with OpenViBE software for the first time. Any help would be appreciated.